# DOMException NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI while xsltProcessor.importStylesheet() with files in local system

Tags: javascript, url, xslt-2.0

I have a local HTML file and I access to it from my browser (Firefox). The page cannot be online for security reasons. Therefore a web-serve can't be implemented.

### My windows File system structure:

- My_Project_Folder:

  - *.HTML
  - assets:

    - *.xslt
    - js_Folder:

      - *.js

The pic bellow is the error from the Firefox debugger.

[Browser console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgaIh.jpg)

It throws a DOMException, when I try to access to the already-loaded stylesheet. It is requested with

1. `xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();`
2. `xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);`
3. `xhttp.responseXML;`

Here, the function where the exception is thrown.

```
`

    /**Generate a document part to be shown in HTML-document
     * 
     * @param {XMLDocument} xml VSF file to be transformed.
     * @param {XMLDocument} xsl XSLT style sheet being used for the VSF.
     * @param {HTMLDocument} document HTML document where the created fragment belongs to.
     * @returns {DocumentFragment} The fragment HTML-document. 
     */
    function createFragSpecification(xml, xsl, document) {
        xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        try {
            xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }

        return xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
    }

`
```

Does anyone have an idea where my mistake is or how can import the style sheet (xsl) using the xsltProcessor?

Comment: Does it work if you have the XSLT file and the Javascript file in the same directory? Browsers are unfortunately rather restrictive when it comes to loading files from the file system, Google by default prevents it completely I think while Firefox has very restrictive permissions, it might be that navigating up is something not allowed.

Comment: Note that you can run a web server to accept connections only on localhost, so if you can't find a solution without a server, you may be able to use a server.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Unfortunately, It doesn't work even if the XSLT file and the Javascript files are in the same folder.

Comment: @JeffLearman I hope I can find a solution in the way it is because I can't use a server due to restrictions with the project's infrastructure.

Comment: I have done various tests here with a current release of Firefox, I have not been able to reproduce the problem with various files, having tested both loading HTML, Javascript and XML and XSLT from one directory as well as loading the Javascript, XML and XSLT from an `assets` subdirectory. You can see the files I created at https://github.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/tree/master/js/2018/jsfilesystemaccess, all those HTML documents load and execute the XSLT just fine when these files sit here in a local copy of the file system.

Comment: You might need to show us minimal but complete files to allow us to reproduce the problem, I am currently not sure what goes wrong, unless there are import or includes in the XSLT that try to load files from further up the directory structure.

Comment: @Martin Honnen you're right! there was an `<xsl:import> ` from further up the directory structure, that I've just noticed it after, I tried out your solution in Github. Thank you!. How can I check off my question as solved?

Comment: I have morphed to comments into an answer you can accept to mark the problem as solved.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and have tested with the files in https://github.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/tree/master/js/2018/jsfilesystemaccess Mozilla Firefox allows you to load an XML or XSLT document with XMLHttpRequest from the same directory or from subdirectories of the file system, you can't however navigate up the directory structure. So your code should work unless there is an import or include that tries to load files from further up the directory structure.